# how to request for permission in `onResume()` in runtime using permissionDispatcher library in android 6 and above

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, permission-denied

I want to request for user's location every time the activity comes into screen (I think my only option here is activity's `onResume()` method) and I want to (and should) support android 6's new runtime permission model.

I am using [permissionDispatcher](https://github.com/hotchemi/PermissionsDispatcher) library and it works perfectly. The problem is as [this issue suggests](https://github.com/hotchemi/PermissionsDispatcher/issues/90), if I call a function which requests a permission in the `onResume()` method and user denies the permission, it will stuck in an infinite loop.

But my problem is that since I want to get the user's location on every appearance of the activity, I cannot think of a different way other than using the `onResume()` method (and hence, getting stuck in an infinite loop if the user denies the permission).

here's a sample of my code:

```
    @NeedsPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
    void startLocationUpdate() {
        mLocationLoadingDialog.show();
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }

    @OnShowRationale(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
    void showRationalForFineLocation(final PermissionRequest request) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setMessage("this app needs your permission to get your location")
                .setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        request.proceed();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("no way", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        request.cancel();
                        exitApp();
                    }
                })
                .setCancelable(false)
                .show();
    }

    @OnPermissionDenied(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
    void showDeniedForFINELOCATION() {
        exitApp();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        RequestSelectorActivityPermissionsDispatcher.onRequestPermissionsResult(this, requestCode, grantResults);

    }

    private void exitApp() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setMessage("you didn't allow us to know where you are, so the application will exit")
                .setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        moveTaskToBack(true);
                        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                        System.exit(1);
                    }
                }).show();
    }
```

what can I do for my situation?

Answer (score 5):

Until unless the permission is so necessary that we have to close the activity without the permission, I don't recommend requesting permissions in onResume().

If you deny a permission without never ask again flag set true, as many number of times onResume() is called that many times you have to request for permissions.

I do understand that if you consider all the possible cases you might want to put it in onResume(), but think that it may also annoy user in some use cases.

I suggest you to put requesting part in onStart() instead of onResume()